# How to perform a conditional cross-tab in R or Excel?

Tags: r, spss, excel, contingency-tables

I recently was given a project which consists of: pulling together words from ~500 small tweets and doing a matrix, which shows which words occur together in which tweets.

I am wondering how I can perform this crosstab (or matrix) to see which words occur together. A basic count will suffice, but it has to be done by `tweetID` (the unique identifier for each tweet).

So I am thinking of something that would look like this on a much larger scale, where a number indicates the amount of times they showed up in the same paragraph:

```
            Ability  Amplify  Ascertain  Aspire  Assimilate
Ability        1        1         0         1         0
Amplify        1        1         0         0         1
Ascertain      0        0         1         1         0
Aspire         1        0         1         1         0
Assimilate     0        1         0         0         1
```

I have tried to use the reshape cast package, as my data is laid out as such:

```
tweetID word
1       Ability
1       Aspire
1       Blah2
2       Ability
2       Aspire
2       Blah3
3       Amplify 
3       Assimilate
```

But have had no luck.

Eventually, we would like to do a sort of network analysis to show which words interact with one another, but I don't necessarily care about the tweetID beyond just helping organize the interactions between words

I have software such as R, SPSS, Tableau and Excel at my disposal, but have hit a bit of a roadblock.

Can anyone point me in the right direction here?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are interested in tools from [text mining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_mining). You are on the right track in thinking about that gigantic matrix - it's called a [sparse matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix), because most of the elements are zeros. Text mining algorithms work off of that. But don't manually do it, because there are R packages that can already do all of these steps for you. Useful R packages would be:
R has some great packages for this:
tm
rtexttools
wordcloud
twitteR (this is for pulling tweets in real time, great tool, you just need a Twitter account)

They all have good vignettes that can walk you through what you are doing.

As far as methods to find common terms, the dominant method to do this is cluster analysis: you look at how tweets can be clustered together based on the terms included in them. There are numerous cluster analysis algorithms used, ranging from more rudimentary (like k-means) to much more complex (like latent Dirichlet allocation, or LDA). I would not recommend getting into something like LDA until you are pretty comfortable with what it is actually doing. I'm no expert in it, but when I've used it I've found it fairly difficult to interpret the results.

You also want to consider how you will clean up the tweets. This includes things like:
- Removing stop words (like "the" "is", etc.
- removing case (i.e. making everything lower case)
- dealing with emoticons
- dealing with negation ("no","not","isn't","ain't",etc)
- stemming (e.g. converting words like "transformer", "transforming" to "transform")

This [Web page](http://www.rdatamining.com/examples/text-mining) gives a decent introduction with working examples in R.

There is actually a substantial amount of [work](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=text%20mining%20tweets&btnG=&as_sdt=1%2C9&as_sdtp=) on text mining tweets. A lot of it is for sentiment analysis, a thriving area. Some of it is to identify themes, though in my limited experience the shortness of tweets makes it very difficult to extract too much common meaning, though if you have a subset of tweets that are related to a similar topic you may be better off.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The data has actually been already formatted in this way, cleaned, and is prepared for analysis (which will be done by a colleague). From my end, there's nothing else that needs to be done.
So really the sparse table is all that I have to do.. Unfortunately it has stumped me thus far!